# JPEG data from a camera module, how to display the image on a computer?

Tags: camera, hex, jpeg, microcontroller

I have a microcontroller with at camera connected to it. The camera module can take JPEG pictures. I have manage to capture JPEG images (I think) but I'm not sure how to display the images I receive. I get a bit stream from the MCU in hex format. I simply copy the output I get form terminal window and paste it into a hex editor and save it at .jpg file. Is this right? I can't display the images.

Here are the output for a 80x60 JPEG picture in hex. 
`FF D8 FF E0 01 14 A4 64 94 60 11 10 00 00 0A FF DB 04 30 86 67 65 87 77 99 8A C1 4D CB BC 19 12 13 F1 41 D1 A1 F1 E1 D1 A1 C1 C2 02 42 E2 72 02 22 C2 31 C1 C2 83 72 92 C3 03 13 43 43 41 F2 73 93 D3 83 23 C2 E3 33 43 2F FD B0 43 19 99 CB C1 8D D1 83 22 11 C2 13 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2F FC 40 1F 00 15 11 11 11 00 00 00 00 12 34 56 78 9A BF FC 40 B5 10 02 13 32 43 55 44 00 17 D1 23 04 11 51 22 13 14 16 13 51 61 72 27 11 43 28 19 1A 18 23 42 B1 C1 15 52 D1 F0 24 33 62 72 82 9A 16 17 18 19 1A 25 26 27 28 29 2A 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DA E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA FF C4 01 F1 03 11 11 11 11 10 00 00 01 23 45 67 89 AB FF C4 0B 51 10 21 24 43 47 54 40 12 77 01 23 11 45 21 31 61 24 15 17 61 71 13 22 32 81 81 44 29 1A 1B 1C 19 23 33 52 F0 15 62 72 D1 A1 62 43 4E 12 5F 11 71 81 91 A2 62 72 82 92 A3 53 63 73 83 93 A4 34 44 54 64 74 84 94 A5 35 45 55 65 75 85 95 A6 36 46 56 66 76 86 96 A7 37 47 57 67 77 87 97 A8 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98 A9 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99 AA 2A 3A 4A 5A 6A 7A 8A 9A AB 2B 3B 4B 5B 6B 7B 8B 9B AC 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C AD 2D 3D 4D 5D 6D 7D 8D 9D AE 2E 3E 4E 5E 6E 7E 8E 9E AF 2F 3F 4F 5F 6F 7F 8F 9F AF FC 00 11 80 3C 05 03 12 10 21 11 31 11 FF DA 0C 31 02 11 31 10 3F 0E 3E F2 28 C3 F9 51 21 55 E4 45 44 F2 C2 8A 94 EE CE 98 C2 D1 2F 68 1E 1F 8F 55 B8 91 E5 5C 43 18 E7 DC D5 5B FF 0E 46 D2 4B 25 B9 FD D8 3C 55 FB 46 8C 1C 39 A7 64 63 49 67 E4 82 3B D4 36 AC FA 9C 49 D4 96 14 9B BB 15 48 F2 A3 DA F4 E8 19 6D 23 E3 B5 59 28 D8 E9 4D A3 9F 52 B4 A4 8A A1 32 CA EE 1C 54 35 7D 8A 48 E4 16 D2 51 19 BA 91 78 DD 33 54 DD 41 24 FA D4 45 9E B6 8D 68 6F 69 77 12 DA D8 35 BA AE D3 26 72 7E B5 AB 6D A5 89 E0 D8 78 6A E1 A9 C6 DF 2B 6D 1C 77 8C 34 F1 A6 BA 2C 67 96 AC CF 0B 5A 9B 8F 15 B8 6E 99 C9 AA D9 99 CA 4E 5B 9E F7 5A A2 CA 0E D4 35 9E EE D4 37 72 12 27 B3 45 EA 2A 85 D2 2C 68 70 BD 28 41 63 CC 24 D4 65 36 51 C0 ED C0 A8 2D 98 CF 70 91 8E 72 6B 14 B4 3D 72 51 5A 1B F1 48 04 E1 3F BB 5D 35 94 AA 91 02 7A 56 B4 D1 C6 DE 87 17 E3 09 D6 F6 F5 4E 42 AC DF 08 07 6F 12 6D 5E 14 F3 49 B6 3A 90 70 48 F7 5B 79 51 60 5F 5C 51 25 C0 C5 23 1E 62 94 B3 8E 79 AC AB CB 8E D1 A8 5C F2 4B A8 DC 4C 11 41 38 1D 2B A9 F0 E8 6D A9 5D DD CD 28 C2 C0 98 19 F5 34 B6 46 F3 97 BA CA C9 F3 6A 33 95 E9 E6 1C 7E 75 BA 25 31 DB F3 D0 AD EB 43 26 2A 69 16 D7 D6 E6 66 40 7D E9 BA 36 93 67 63 A9 16 87 1B 98 D1 28 D8 6E 4E 51 B3 3B 64 57 85 47 20 61 51 63 16 8A 72 EE AC 9B BD E3 34 58 47 98 5E DD C9 DF C8 CB 83 B5 B1 5D 4E 81 AB BD A7 85 AF EE D2 4D 97 0E 58 0C 7E 05 73 CF 64 74 D4 4B A1 9D A5 DE 57 CC BD 73 92 6B A9 2E 6D E7 8F 60 70 9A E8 8C 94 53 6C 9E CE 63 69 68 61 F3 81 47 1C D6 54 77 AD 65 AB C5 21 93 72 BB 62 89 36 DA 34 49 2A 7E A7 AA 58 BC 77 16 E8 DD C8 A9 E4 B6 52 28 E6 31 7B 23 3E E2 0B 9A C6 BC 8F 0F A5 3B 93 63 C9 AD D1 25 B8 B9 8E 45 DC 49 3C D4 33 4B 3D 85 BB DB 52 61 63 9A C9 C2 E9 33 09 55 B5 67 16 C2 D6 FD 18 8C 1E 7D 2B 49 6E 56 67 1C 62 B4 8C 54 8E BA 72 5C C5 6B DB E6 48 70 B2 1C FD 6A A2 CD 2B 42 AC 58 92 E4 13 49 AB 44 D6 BC AD 68 A3 D7 BC 1F AB 0B AD 3A 32 CD F3 01 CD 74 CF 76 08 C8 A8 D4 C5 CE E5 59 AE 55 D4 FA D7 3F 7F 73 B9 CF 4A A4 43 67 93 58 CD E5 5D B1 63 F7 85 69 49 2C 72 70 DC 8F A5 74 52 B5 8F 37 17 17 ED 5B 45 79 F4 8B 69 60 69 E2 72 8E 66 B2 6C E7 9F CC 68 F3 9C 77 15 35 62 AE F1 3A 30 53 94 FE 2E 82 CA 9B 5C F9 CF 81 F5 A9 DD B5 B3 36 EC 76 AC DE AA C7 5D 47 79 5C EB FC 09 7B 24 6C 61 6C 8E 7A 57 A1 06 6A 2C 43 BD C8 25 DE 0E 6B 2B 55 2F 19 CD 96 AD 1E 52 9F 2C E9 8A D5 01 03 81 5A 57 74 72 E3 17 BC 8B 6E 0D 36 5E 07 4A E6 B4 55 0D 74 F9 F5 35 55 F7 41 81 EA 4B A9 42 A6 E8 66 A5 D3 7E 5B B1 18 03 69 EA 2B 96 EF 99 1E 84 D2 3A FD 31 16 1D 62 13 18 03 72 82 6B DD 02 A3 3E 95 A7 41 4B 71 64 45 29 D2 BF 55 3B 2D DC AF A5 2B 93 D0 FF D9`

Comment: Are you sure the data is being saved as binary data?  When you say that you're copying the data from a terminal window that makes me wonder if you're pasting ASCII data into the file.  ASCII data will not work.  Can you redirect the output from the terminal window directly to a binary file?

Comment: @kkrambo I'm not sure of that. I have tried to use Matlab now to read from the COM-port to fetch the data. I was able to do that, but what should I do when I save the file as a .bin file?

Comment: Open a real .jpg file with your hex editor for an example.  The first two bytes should be 0xFF and 0xD8 (like you displayed above).  When you create your .jpg file from the data, you need to ensure that you're not saving it as ASCII data (i.e., text).  If it is ASCII then the first byte will be the ASCII code for an 'F', which is 0x46.  In other words if the first two bytes of your file are 0xFF, 0xD8 then it is binary.  But if the first two bytes are 0x46, 0x46 then that is ASCII text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to solve my problem. There was not a problem with the JPEG file it self, or actually it was, but the reason for that was that the function sprintf() in C removes the zeros under decimal 15. If you have the value 0x00000111, this is decimal 7 and hex 0x07, but my code only prints 0x7. Thats the reason I could not display the image.